# How to fill a table in asp.net using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on a small web application using asp.net mvc and angularjs. 
I came across a problem where I need to pass an array of user data to my cshtml file and present it in a table. However, all I get is an empty table. To pass the array I use ViewBag, and to fill the table I use ng-reperat on the array, I don't understand what I am missing here.

Here is the code of my controller where I create my array and put it into ViewBag

```
 public class DashboardController : Controller
 {

        public IActionResult DashboardV6()
        {
            UserManager userManager = SchemaDataManager.getEntityDataManager<UserManager>();
            UserEntity[] users = (UserEntity[])userManager.getAll<UserEntity>();
            ArrayList usersList = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
            {

                User u = new User();
                u.token = users[i].token;
                u.username = users[i].username;
                u.createDate = users[i].createDate;
                usersList.Add(u);
            }

            ViewBag.userList = usersList;

            return View();
        }

        public class User
        {
            public String token { get; set; }
            public String username { get; set; }
            public DateTime createDate { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

Here is my cshtml code:

```
    @{
        Layout = null;
        var list = ViewBag.userList as ArrayList; 
     }
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Users Table 
        <!----small>Chaning data</!--small-->
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div ng-controller="DashboardV6Controller as table2">
            <form ng-submit="table2.addUser()" class="form-inline">
                <table datatable="ng" dt-options="table2.dtOptions" dt-column-defs="table2.dtColumnDefs" class="row-border hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="number" name="id" ng-model="table2.user2Add.userID" value="" class="form-control" />
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="table2.user2Add.userName" value="" class="form-control" />
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="table2.user2Add.userEmail" value="" class="form-control" />
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
                                        <span class="btn-label">
                                            <em class="fa fa-plus"></em>
                                        </span>Add
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>User Token</th>
                            <th>User Name</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="user in list">
                            <td>{{user.token}}</td>
                            <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                            <td>{{ user.createDate}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" ng-click="table2.modifyUser($index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">
                                    <em class="fa fa-edit"></em>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" ng-click="table2.removeUser($index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                                    <em class="fa fa-trash-o"></em>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: angularjs controller and mvccontroller are different

Comment: Oh, I see, so angularjs controller handles the user actions with the ui, and the MVC controller handles the url requests?